# The SDK platform-tools version (24.0.3) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 25 [Warning]

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, build-tools

I know this has been asked on SO many times but not able to get it solved for me.

`Main Project Gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

`App Module Gradle File`

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.something"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

So the question is from where does it taking the build tool version `24.0.3` as I have set it to `25.0.1`

Just confused!!

Comment: Are you used Support lib version 25.0.1 ?
 `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'`

Comment: @Basi Yes indeed!

Comment: Clean-Rebuild-Restart

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Clean-Rebuild-Restart done but same result. Also done the `Invalidate Case & Restart` not working either!

Comment: Check out your library modules it will be using this version.

Comment: Check with the SDK Manager that you have the latest version of `Android SDK Tools` and `Android SDK Platform-Tools`.

Comment: Please do check your SDK Manager

Comment: @RiccardoCiovati Ya don't know how but after updating to the latest version it's solved this issue.

Answer (score 5):

There 3 steps:
You can have a try like this. I have same problem too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this way

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.something"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }
```

and add compile `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and resolved by performing following steps:

**1.** Please try to Uninstall your older platform-tools, such as `24.0.3`

[image]

**2.** Then install the recommended platform-tools.

**3.** Restart Android studio, that will be OK